# How to set the correct setTargetResolution size to analyze an image with object detection?

Tags: android, kotlin, object-detection

I'm using CameraX with object detection to analyze the frames from the camera and i'm having trouble setting the right size in order to make an overlay that shows what object is currently being detected.

```
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .setTargetResolution(size)
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()
            .also { it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, imageAnalyzer) }
```

I have a CustomView(Overlay) that i give the Rect that `boundingBox` gives me and i draw that.

I have tried some things but the results are inconsistent:

If i do: `val size = Size(DisplayMetrics().heightPixels, DisplayMetrics().widthPixels)`

- The app works fine in all versions of android but when i try to get the `boundingBox` rect and set up the overlay, the borders dont match with the object in the screen.

If i do: `val size = Size(224,224)` like it sugguest in one of the android codelabs

This is from the codelabs github:

```
// This sets the ideal size for the image to be analyse, CameraX will choose the
// the most suitable resolution which may not be exactly the same or hold the same               
// aspect ratio
.setTargetResolution(Size(224, 224))
```

- In this case in android R the app runs fine and still the overlay borders are off and in older versions like Android Q and Oreo, it keeps opening the camera one time after another, like a glitch and it freezes the app

If i do: `val size = Size(1280, 720)` like the example in the ImageAnalysis Documentation

- The borders are off too but the app works fine in all the Android versions
- Tried the same with 640x480 and got the same result
- If i do 480x640 or 720x1280 i get the glitch that freezes the app

I only could make it work using  `val size = Size(DisplayMetrics.widthPixels, DisplayMetrics().heightPixels)`

- This shows the correct borders that match the object in screen but it only works in Android R, with olders versions i get the same glith where the camera keeps opening and freezes the screen

[image]              [image]

The first photo is with the borders in the incorrect position and the second one is when its working correctly.

If anyone has any ideas of what im doing wrong and how to fix this, i would appreciate the help.
Sorry for the long post and Thanks.

Comment: Do you want resolution or size?

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, my issue is with the Size(..., ...), I tried multiple variations but everyone gives me a problem

Comment: What is `ImageAnalysis`? I think you can use OpenCV and draw the rectangle with using  x, y points. Or there are a bunch of libraries and examples.

Comment: The issue probably has more to do with the difference in aspect ratio between preview and image analysis than size. MLKit's object detection doesn't require a high resolution (like preview's resolution) to be able to detect objects in camera frames. Forcing Preview and ImageAnalysis to have the same aspect ratio makes the coordinates conversion easier to perform. You can take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/husaynhakeem/android-playground/tree/master/FaceDetectorSample) for an example.

Comment: Perfect, i tried your app in the emulator and it keeps opening the camera in Android API 29 or less and freezes, and works fine in API 30, do you know if this is an emulator problem and in the real devices works fine? My phone has API 30 and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to guess it's an emulator problem. In general, testing your camera app should be done on a physical device, as you may run into some issues on emulators that you wouldn't otherwise see on a real device. I think there's been a rehaul of HALs on emulators running android R (API level 30), so in theory, it should be safe to test on them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import from

> import android.util.Size

Here is code snippet

```
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis
        .Builder()
        // RGBA output is needed.
        .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
        .setTargetResolution(Size(1280,720))
```

*Note 1280 is my preview view width and 720 is height, aspect ratio should remain constant so you can add variable like

```
.setTargetResolution(Size(previewView.width, previewView.height))
```